# Get Facebook Media-id for instagram post from url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

If I have a instagram post is there anyway to get the facebook id for an instagram post? To be clear, if I were to look at https://www.instagram.com/p/Bcqn51ynrd5/ I am able to find the instagram media-id by doing one of two things:

- https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?callback=&url=https://www.instagram.com/p/Bcqn51ynrd5/
- https://www.instagram.com/p/Bcqn51ynrd5?__a=1

However, neither of these are the media-id associated with facebook's new [instagram graph insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights). If I already have the facebook media-id I am able to get the instagram media-id through facebook graph by calling `graph.facebook.com/{facebook-media-id}?fields=ig_id` but I am unable to find the inverse. Is this possible?

Comment: Alex is Victor providing you with the solution you were seeking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.  It is listed as limitation in the [Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/insights) documentation.

To list current limitations:

> - We only store 2 years worth of metrics data.
> - You can only get insights for a single Instagram Business account at a time.
> - **You cannot get insights for Facebook Pages.**
> - Stories insights are only available for 24 hours, even if the stories are archived or highlighted. If you want to get the latest
>     insights for a story before it expires, set up a Webhook for the
>     Instagram topic and subscribe to the story_insights field.

Comment: tukan, can you elaborate how Facebook page is related to Instagram media-id? I agree with Alex's point: the Instagram post's media-id returned via Instagram API is different from the one returned via Facebook Graph API.

Comment: @VictorStagurov what you have posted below is what Alex already did.  He knows that facebook's `media-id` can get him instagram `media-id`.  What he wanted is *...to find the inverse...*, he wants to have instangram's ` media_id/insights` to get him facebook's `media-id` which is listed as limitation and currently not possible.

Comment: you didn't answer my question: why you highlighted **insights for Facebook pages** as the limitation and how it's related to Instagram insights/media-id? My solution is a valid one. Alex needs Instagram insights for a particular post. He has Instagram post URL, using which he finds `instagram-media-id`. Facebook Graph API doesn't provide any insights for `instgram-media-id`, so he needs to find `facebook-media-id`. There is no endpoint to do so either. The solution below allows to find `facebook-media-id` by `instgram-media-id` - and this is the _inverse_ he's asking about.

Answer (score 4):

Call `graph.facebook.com/{instagram-business-account-id}/media?fields=ig_id`

which returns a list of both Facebook and Instagram media-ids:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ig_id": "1729885037886968354",
      "id": "16961190105043123"
    },
    {
      "ig_id": "1714698694055731973",
      "id": "16949739045077321"
    }
    ...
```

then find corresponding Facebook's media-id you can get the insights for.

Also, instead of `ig_id` use `shortcode` field in `graph.facebook.com/{instagram-business-account-id}/media?fields=shortcode` and traverse list searching directly for short code, so you may skip "finding Instagram media-id by short code" step.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. I was able to convert the Instagram short code to its id using a python script, and then I sent a request to this API to get the media_id for Facebook. Thanks!